# Show data of another database in templates, not from django models

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, database

I just want to know if **is it possible to show the data from the collections of my other two MongoDBs in my Django templates**? Not just the ones from the django database.

This is what my app does: 
I have a form for the user and that uses my models database. I use two other python programs to process that, via subprocess in Celery, and each of them produces a MongoDB for the results.

I want to show those results in my templates, but I don't know if what I'm doing is correct, or if Django offers some help.

Here is what I've done so far:

At the start of *views.py*, to check connection and access the documents:

```
#This is calling my model and form 
from .forms import SampleForm
from .models import Sample

....#some code here
import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

sys.path.append(settings.APP1_PATH)
sys.path.append(settings.APP2_PATH)

#MongoDB connection for App1
try:
    app1_db = pymongo.MongoClient(settings.MONGO_HOST, settings.MONGO_PORT)[settings.app1_MONGO_DB]
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
    logger.error("Could not connect to App1 MongoDB: %s" % e)

#For the GridFS connection
try:
    conn=pymongo.MongoClient(settings.MONGO_HOST, settings.MONGO_PORT)
    db = conn.app1fs 
    app1fs_db = GridFS(db)
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
    logger.error("Could not connect to App1FS MongoDB: %s" % e)


#MongoDB connection for App2
try:
    app2_db = pymongo.MongoClient(settings.MONGO_HOST, settings.MONGO_PORT)[settings.App2_MONGO_DB]
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
    logger.error("Could not connect to App2 MongoDB: %s" % e)

def results_detail(request, id): 
    sample_instance = get_object_or_404(Sample, id=id)    
    context = {
        "name": sample_instance.get_sample_name,
        "sample": sample_instance
    }
    return render(request, "analysis/results_detail_base.html", context)

def app1_results_detail(request):
    #call MongoDB document's collections then pass to template
    #App1's
    #insert here..
    context = {
    }
    return render(request, "analysis/app1_results_detail.html", context)
```

For now, my templates for app1 and app2 results are still blank because I don't know how to access them in the views. I already read inspectdb for use of legacy database but it is not applicable for Mongo database. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You clearly know how to access MongoDB, since you set up the connections and you presumably read and write in your Celery tasks. So what is stopping you doing it in the views too? Of course, templates will render whatever data you pass to them, wherever it comes from.

Comment: Thanks, I was quite hesitant about the logic of my code. I'll try it if it will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, you can connect to that db, make a query store that {key:value} in  params/context variables of `return render(request, template.html, params)`

Use the key in templates like this: `{{key}}` where ever you want to use the value associated to this key.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll get back to you on what happens. Because the two apps are actually two python programs outside my django app.

Comment: the other 2 apps, if they are django apps, then you can add them to this django project. Otherwise, if they are just methods, you can import them as functions and use the outputs returned by the methods.